# Caching text and images using Volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

One of the feature of the Volley library for network operations in android is that it caches text and images into disk so by changing orientation the application does not have to download images and texts again. this piece of code uses this feature:

```
public class AppsActivity extends Activity {

static public Typeface font;
List<Application> appsList;
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
AppAdapter adapter;
GridView gv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apps);
    font =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/BMitra.ttf");
    appsList = new ArrayList<Application>();
    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    adapter = new AppAdapter(this, appsList);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get("http://appline.ir/index.php/android.feed?limitstart=");
    if (entry != null)
    {
        fetch the data from cache
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            parseXmlString(data);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    } 
    else 
    {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.GET, "http://appline.ir/index.php/android.feed?limitstart=", new Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String res)
            {
                parseXmlString(res);
            }

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AppsActivity.this,
                    AppDetailActivity.class);

            Application app;
            app=appsList.get(position);
            intent.putExtra("title", app.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("imageUrl", app.getImageUrl());
            intent.putExtra("description", description.get(position+1));
            //              intent.putExtra("title", app.getTitle());

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}

public void parseXmlString(String string)
{

    XmlPullParserFactory parser;
    XmlPullParser xml = null;

    try
    {
        parser =XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xml = parser.newPullParser();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(string);
        xml.setInput(reader);
    }   
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    int event;
    String text = null;
    try {

        event = xml.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            String name=xml.getName();
            switch (event)
            {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                text = xml.getText();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if(name.equals("title")){
                    title.add(text);
                }
                else if(name.equals("link")){   
                    //                        link = text;
                }
                else if(name.equals("description")){

                    description.add(text);
                }
                else{
                }
                break;
            }        
            event = xml.next(); 
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(description.size());
    for(int i = 1; i < description.size(); i++)
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse((description.get(i)));
        Elements links = doc.select("p"); // a with href
        Elements pngs = links.select("img[src$=.png]");
        String image = pngs.attr("src");
        appsList.add(new Application(Html.fromHtml(title.get(i)).toString(), image, font));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My question is that, when I debug the code(using `System.out` in if clause for cache), I figured out that we never get a hit on cache. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the server dose not allow you to cache those files, in order to confirm my answer you can do one of these things:

1. download this plug in (RESTClient) for mozilla and send your request and check the header file for cache control
2. set break point in `headerValue = headers.get("Cache-Control");` at `HttpHeaderParse` class and see whats going on.

all of those solutions only valid if you set your requests to be cashable `shouldCache();`

and just in order to accept my answer faster, look at cache control :-)

[image]

Comment: look again at my answer !!

Comment: tanx for the answer, is there anyway to override caching policy?

Comment: yes two ways i know: change `parseCacheHeaders` from class `HttpHeaderParser` or store your response in volley requestqueue cache by key value of urls. for image you must also add width and height if you are using networkimage. read source code !!!

Comment: as I use volley.jar I think the first solution is not an option, could you please explain a little more about second one? links?

Comment: I tried `request.setShouldCache(true)` but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: it must not solve your issue man because the server dose not allow the volley to store it, volley first check response header and then check your request to cache it or not, in this example server dose not allow him to cache anything.

Comment: I thought it was a way to override the policy, can you explain your solution about that?

Comment: in onResponse listener put your response in to the volley cache by key value of corresponding url.